# Angular drag and drop - how to pass a parameter to the onStart callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

**THE SITUATION:**

I have an app that make use of angular [drag and drop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).

Everything is working fine except one thing.
I need to pass one parameter in the onStart callback function, but i don't know how.
I search around and try several possibilities but without success.
The function itself is working, has been called and properly executed, the only problem i have is to pass a parameter to it.

**THE CODE:**

In this example there one of the attempt i have made.

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="thumbnail" data-drop="true" ng-model='todo_list' jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop:'update_item()'}">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in todo_list track by $index" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="todo_list" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, onStart:'set_board_item_id_panel(event, ui, {board_item_id: item.board_item_id})'}">{{item.title}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i pass a parameter in the callback function of angular [drag and drop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like you are missing the closing parenthesis for set_board_item_id_panel(   ?

Comment: Thank you to notice it. It probably went away making many attempts. I edit the question. But still is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to pass in parameters `event` and `ui`, those are the first 2 default arguments.

Replace ...

```
onStart:'set_board_item_id_panel(event, ui, {board_item_id: item.board_item_id})'
```

With ...

```
onStart:'set_board_item_id_panel({board_item_id: item.board_item_id})'
```

Then in your Controller do this ...

```
....
$scope.set_board_item_id_panel = function (event, ui, board_item_id) {
    console.log(board_item_id);
}
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working. In the while i was creating a Plunker. I have already correct it. Maybe you can include in your answer so can be a further help. There is a multiple list with callback functions onStart and Ondrop:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yi4xzLHms5PZprFpkpj1?p=preview